# Angular 4 - Error 404 while redirect to https with .htaccess

Tags: angular, .htaccess, https

In production, I build my application with :

`ng build --prod --aot false`

I have two Apache configurations, one in vhost, other in .htaccess file on the root of my dist folder.

In my vhost :

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

In my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
```

When I launch my application, click on links it's work, I'm in https.
When I refresh my page or I type directly URL in the browser, I have a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

make sure you `.htaccess` file is available in `public_html` folder where you whole code deploy, i hope this will help.

Comment: Where I put the https section ?

Comment: if you follow above thing this is enough to load things properly.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^othersite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.othersite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mainwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: I replace my https code by yours in .htaccess but I have an error of loop.